# How to check the presentation end with PowerPoint.Interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm showing a Powerpoint presentation inside a page with ASP.NET and I have only the **Next** and **Previous** buttons.

What I would like to check is whether it's the presentation end or not as soon as the user click in **Next** button.

That's how I'm trying to do this:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            presesntation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next();
            if (presesntation.SlideShowWindow.View.State.Equals(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideShowState.ppSlideShowDone))
            {
                if (this.PresentationEnd != null)
                {
                    this.PresentationEnd(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }

                btnNext.Visible = false;
                btnPrevious.Visible = false;
                foreach (Process proc2 in Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT"))
                {
                    proc2.Kill();
                }
            }
            ///Cria um delay de 1 seg para o proximo clique no botão
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

The line that checks the presentation end is `if (presesntation.SlideShowWindow.View.State.Equals(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideShowState.ppSlideShowDone))` but it doesn't work with some `.ppsx` presentations. Although it works with every `.pps` presentation

How do I check the presentation end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your next click handler check the current slide's Slide.Index to see if it's equal to the presentation Slides.Count.  If so, you're already on the last slide (ie, you're at the end of the presentation).

You could then end the show yourself rather than trying to sort out whether the user has ended it.